# Which application is better to develop for the following requirement

Tags: c#, .net, application-design

I need to store data received from a remote device, i.e Application needs to run 24 hours so that it can capture data and store it in database.

I am confusing whether to create a console application, web application or any other i need to develop which will run continuously.

Comment: Well I'm pretty certain you wouldn't want a console application, but whether or not it's a Windows Service or Web Service, I guess that depends on the needs of the device and its available connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the application developed, then send the data to a web service. if you don't, consider creating a web page, either using ASP.Net or something like JQuery Mobile and push data to HTTP Handlers or Web Service.

If you go down the web service route, create a web method that accepts a request object and returns a response object. It should be a pretty simple design.